# Can exif-parser extract XMP (Extensible Metadata Platform) tags?

Tags: javascript, exif-js

I'm looking for a Javascript package to extract an extended image tag *Projection Type*
to detect between image with projection (e.g. sphere image) and image without projection.

I found another Javascript library (*exifreader*) that extracts *XMP* (Extensible Metadata Platform) tags including the *Projection Type* tag.
Since I'm looking to use well-maintained, and optimized code I compared between the 2 Javascript *exif-parser*, and *exifreader*.
In terms of popularity and size, *exif-parser* is clearly a winner (see the table below).

But I don't find any reference to extended metadata or *XMP* flags in the *exif-parser* code.

**[image: Can] the Javascript package *exif-parser* extract *XMP* tags?**

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Software Recommendations belong to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to chime in with my own library [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr). I've written it because the others out there either aren't maintained, isomorphic, don't support HEIC photos, can't parse segments other than TIFF/EXIF (in your case you look for XMP), aren't efficient, read the whole file, or all of the above.

I've written exifr to be the fastest and also most efficient. And yes it does read XMP. I'd be happy if you would try it out. There's a [playground](http://mutiny.cz/exifr/) for experimenting with images, or check out the [repository and docs](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr).

There's one catch though. To keep the exifr's size down, it does not parse the XML. It only exports the XML string for you. There's plenty of XML parsers out there and many ways to parse XML (since the tag can have both attributes and children).

PS: Right now I'm just a days off from publishing version 3.0.0, which is a complete rewrite. It's already in repo's master branch, but it's not yet published on npm.

Comment: I was not able to detect the "Projection Type" tag, using exifr library (installed from npm). Also, can exifr extract tags from other file formats, e.g. png file? (exifreader can't - it returns an error message: "invalid image format")

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz ExifReader maintainer here. Since version 3.1.0 there is (some) support for PNG.

Comment: @AvnerMoshkovitz exifr maintainer here. As of version 4 there is an XMP parser that can parse tags like "projection tag" and png support is in the works.